# PCA: Is it better to have stronger correlation between input variables?

Tags: correlation, pca

If input variables are uncorrelated, they would be able to measure 
different dimensions of data.

However, this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXU1ktaVcdI    @ 3:25

says it's not good to have uncorrelated input variables.

What is correct and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCA is used to create uncorrelated variables from correlated ones in this context. So, yes, it's better to have uncorrelated ones. And you create them from correlated ones.